# Initiating Add-In only when Appointment Item is Open through Visual studios

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, ribbon

I have a Outlook Add-in built in VB.Currently whenever I run the Add-in through visual Studios it loads Outlook App and starts the Add-in functionality.
But I want to load the Add-In only when the Appointment item is open in Outlook.
Do we have a way to this? How to Add Button only on Appointment Item through Vb?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter when Outlook loads your addin? You can chose to do nothing until the user opens an appointment. This is the same as not loading your addin.

Comment: I am currently in testing phase.In my Add-in I am setting references to the Calendar Item.So when it Loads on Outlook Startup,the references are set to null and I get an error.

Comment: So don't set a reference on startup.  Which item are you referencing?

Comment: Referencing to A Calendar item.Any Appointment which is open by Witing: Dim cal As Outlook.AppointmentItem , cal = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Comment: Trap the Application.Inspectors.NewInspector evemt. Wh3n the event fires, use Inspector object passed as the parameter to your event handler and read the Inspector.CurrentItem property. Keep in mind that there can be multiple open items, so you need to have a list of items. Remove an item from the list when Inspector.Close event fires.